# How to run the Savage 2 after install?

Tags: games

I have downloaded and installed the "`Savage2-2.1.0.8-linux-installer.run`", But I'm not able to run this game.. The game installed properly. Please tell me how to play?

Comment: In non-vague terms, why aren't you able to run it?

Comment: you should have an Icon at the desktop.

Comment: How were you trying to run it?

Answer (score 1):

This is where I found my answers.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1139883.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Terminal
Navigate to your installation

```
/home/user/Savage2/

**./savage2.bin**
```